# R and data.table package syntax in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, r, syntax, data.table, statet

I'am using Eclipse and StatET to script in R.

I am using the great data.table package which introduce the syntax **:=**

For eclipse it is a syntax error but it is not the case in the context of this package.

Is there a way to make Eclipse consider **:=** as correct ?

Many thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to file a feature request to the author of StatET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `':='(a = b)`, than it will not highlight it.